# problem when upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: upgrade, updates

When upgrading to 13.04 from 12.10 during 'Setting new software channels' the following error message comes.

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/partner/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

There were several more of the above type of messages. Then it aborts upgrading. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry if I were you, that is what you get when you try to refresh you package list.
That's what `sudo apt-get update` does.
However I guess that the installation adds new sources and rerun `sudo apt-get update` and there is the problem.

I would advice you to wait or try to get a better (wired?) connection and then retry.
Maybe try `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal even if I think since the upgrade has aborted, it should have removed the new sources for raring.

My guess would be that to many people are upgrading so the server failed to respond.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get update in the terminal. But still I get the same messages. How should i upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. It was the canonical repositories that were the problem in my case - commenting them out of /etc/apt/sources.list allowed the upgrade to proceed smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

try a clean

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```